# Simple for loop in R to append the correct values to a vector?

Tags: python, r

All I am trying to do is loop through rows of a matrix and do simple arithmetic. In python this is so simple but I'm having trouble making a complete vector in R. I want to sum the values across each row, and the final vector should be (3 7), but it keeps saying it is 4.

```
myVector <- vector(mode= "numeric", length=0)
tab = matrix( c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
tab
myVector
for (i in nrow(tab)) {
    ourSum=0

    for (j in ncol(tab)) {
        ourSum = ourSum + tab[i, j]}
myVector <- append(myVector, ourSum)
}
myVector
length(myVector)
```

Comment: `rowSums(tab)` is what you want.

Comment: The reason that I am doing this is because I want to be able to append values to a vector  with a for loop and I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: So I'm trying to work on learning how to do this with a simple example.

Comment: One problem is in `i in nrow(tab)`  It should be `i in 1:nrow(tab)`.  If you must use a `for()` loop, then make it simple `for(i in 1:nrow(tab)) myVector[i] <- sum(tab[i, ])`

Comment: Thank you!!! Now it is working properly. That was super frustrating.

Answer (score -3):

Why not apply the sum operator to the rows of the matrix?

apply(tab, 1, sum)

I see that you do not like the rowSums solution but loops are generically to be avoided.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: tab = matrix( c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) apply(tab, 1, sum)

Comment: In your answer, please.